# Technical term for words that are almost completely pejorated

Tags: terminology, sociolinguistics

My question is to some extent similar to [this one](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20286/is-there-a-general-term-for-certain-words-or-phrases-that-are-socially-acceptabl). Unlike the infamous n-word, the word **Negro** was originally not so objectionable as it is nowadays, but nowadays it is considered acceptable only in polite historical contexts or in specific proper names. The word is disfavored, but it is not the case that the word is offensive under every circumstance.

The process of an inoffensive word becoming pejorative is a form of semantic drift known as [pejoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pejorative#Pejoration_and_melioration). However, sometimes the process of pejoration is not completed, which makes the appropriate terminology elusive. Is there a specific term for this partial process?

Comment: There isn't a technical term for such small steps in pejoration, any more than there is for small steps in diphthong formation, like the difference between the diphthongized Englisn vowel phoneme /eʸ/ and the phonemic diphthong /oy/.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the context, it might be considered **pejorative** (usable but insulting) or **taboo** (not appropriate to use).

Neither of these are black-and-white categories; words can be varying degrees of pejorative and varying degrees of taboo.